# Winform app with loaded DB connection

Tags: c#, database, winforms, database-connection

I have a question regarding problem i am solving. I am editing an old Winform app; currently the only part I need  does not take input from the user(automated program). However the form contains database connection settings that program uses. Currently the program needs the user to press a button to start the process (code is associated with the button). Do i need to convert whole app to Console App or is there an easier way to automate this process without messing with the database connection settings.

Comment: Can't you take the code that is called by the button and move it somewhere else?

Comment: The program right now is set up so that connection and configuration settings are saved into the form. The problem is that's the only code I need. So the final app, if I rewrite it in WinForm, would look like a small window(form) with one button.

Comment: We you want this to be "headless" or automatic. So either remove the button and call the code on Form_Load (if you want to keep the WinForm), or move the code to a console app. These are only suggestions, and there are many other options you could do, but this might be the easiest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, you have a WinForm that runs code on a button press. You need to turn this into a "headless" or automatic process. Here is what I think based on your description would be the best things to do:

- Remove the button, and have the code that was being ran by the button be called by a more "automatic" process, such as "Form_Load" or a timer.
- Take the code and move it into a console app. As long as you don't ask for user input within the logic, it will run and close itself when it's done.

However, this is just some broad and generic suggestions. You need to look at your code and decide for yourself what to do.